# GWT - Log4j - Develop & Production

Tags: gwt, log4j, datanucleus

I'm using log4j for my GWT application.

I have my log4j.properties in WEB-INF/classes with following content:

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.conversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

# Configure the console as our one appender
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] - %m%n

# tighten logging on the DataNucleus Categories
log4j.category.DataNucleus.JDO=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.Persistence=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.Cache=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.MetaData=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.General=WARN, A1
..
```

My questions are:

- How should I modify my log4j.properties, to use it in
  development mode(output in console) and also for production(output in file) running on my tomcat? Is this possible or is it better to modify the log4j.properties in my ant-script for production mode? Maybe it's better to have two different files?
- The default GWT-project generates DataNucleus entries in the log4j.properties. For what is this used? What's the advantage of DataNucleus? If I want to use just log4j, does it make any sense?
- There is also a logging.properties per default in my WEB-INF folder. For what is this file used?

Answer (score 0):

DataNucleus is used for persisting objects to a datastore using JDO or JPA APIs, as verified by a simple web search. Since its your project, you really ought to know if you're using it.